# Divide Column By Value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to divide a column by a value that will be based on duplicates (1-4) for a macro.

I have tried to work out a formula with no luck

I need it to know that when there is a duplicate to divide column D by the duplicated number

example:

```
column D = 800/ 3 duplicates = 266.66
```

example:

```
column D = 600/ 2 duplicates = 200
```

[image]

Comment: This can be done with a formula: `=D2/COUNTIF(D:D,D2)`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a formula:

```
=D2/COUNTIF(D:D,D2)
```

Comment: As an added note, if you used named ranges, such as table references the calculations will go way quicker, since it would be checking the entire column first. Also I prefer using `COUNTIFS` over `COUNTIF` even if I only use 1 criteria, just because if you need to add more the order doesn't change so it's easier to adjust.